# sys.path.append not working in VSCode but same code works in Spyder?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using Python in VS Code. I need to import modules from other directories, but VS Code is giving me `ModuleNotFoundError`. The same code works fine in Spyder, but I need to use VS Code. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I have added the error and `launch.json` file. Thank you.

Error that I am getting:

> /usr/bin/env /bin/python3 /home/johnkimm/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.6.3/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 53522 -- /mnt/c/Users/hojun/Desktop/QN-Python/Connection/Preparation_1_2_3_John.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/mnt/c/Users/hojun/Desktop/QN-Python/Connection/Preparation_1_2_3_John.py", line 19, in 
> from Preparation_before_EnteringQNMHP import PreparationBeforeEnteringQNMHP
> File "/mnt/c/Users/hojun/Desktop/QN-Python/QNMHP_MATLAB/Preparation_before_EnteringQNMHP.py", line 12, in 
> from DrivingInit import DrivingInit
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DrivingInit'

[image: launch.json]

Comment: Your interpreter can't find the `DriverInit` module.  double check to make sure it exists in your virtual enviornment.  Spyder is probably using a different virtual enviornment

Comment: I think DriverInit exists in the virtual environment. (.venv) johnkimm@LAPTOP-427AUH9J:/mnt/c/Users/hojun/Desktop/QN-Python All the files are in QN-Python file. And also, it's not just DriverInit, but all the files that I imported.

Comment: I am just telling you what caused the error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your project structure, here are two suggestions that might be useful:

1. Import these packages in the `__init__.py` file in the folder where your current `.py` file is located.
2. Use the following code to specify the package path in the `setting.json` file:

```
    "python.analysis.extraPaths":[
        "c:\\workspace\\pythontest\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages",
        "./src",    
    ]
```